# Firewalling Samba

Tags: iptables, samba, firewall

at the moment I'm trying to implement the firewall for my linux file server. Everything is working as expected except form the samba server. I have searched through the internet already but non of the solutions works for me. If the firewall is disabled samba works fine. If I add my samba rules I'm unable to access the server via Windows. What's my mistake?

Many Thanks,
Jonny

```
# 1. Delete all existing rules
iptables -F

# 2. Set default chain policies
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

#Allow traffic on loopback
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

#dhcp
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 67:68 --sport 67:68 -j ACCEPT

#samba server
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.178.0/24 -p udp --dport 137:138 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -d 192.168.178.0/24 -p udp --sport 137:138 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.178.0/24 -p tcp --dport 139 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -d 192.168.178.0/24 -p tcp --sport 139 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -d 192.168.178.0/24 -p tcp --dport 445 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#ntp date
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT

#apt get and wget
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#incoming ssh 
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 50555 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 50555 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#outgoing ssh
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 22  -d 192.168.178.0/24 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#Allow Incoming HTTP and HTTPS
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#Allow Ping from Inside to Outside
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT

#Allow outgoing dns
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -o eth0 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -i eth0 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT

#Logging
iptables -N LOGGING
iptables -A INPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables Packet Dropped: " --log-level 7
iptables -A LOGGING -j DROP
```

Comment: 1. I suggest you use reject rather then drop - http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~peterb/network/drop-vs-reject . 2. I suggest against a default policy of Reject (or drop) as you can easily lock yourself out if you flush your rules. 3. The only thing I see is that you did not allow outgoing traffic on port 445 .

Comment: Your 5th samba rule is wrong. Your are saying "input on this interface" with destination "192.168.178.0/24" only for established sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erase your rule number 5. It should be:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.178.0/24 -p tcp --dport 445 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

And the related connection(new rule)

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -d 192.168.178.0/24 -p udp --sport 445 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

And, to avoid very long rule lists, you could set the default `OUTPUT` policy to `ACCEPT` so, you dont need to create a rule based on established sessions to every `INPUT` rule you have. After some time this will make you create rules faster.

It is somehow an overkill if you don´t have any service that can create excessive traffic output without you knowing. Or, create a specific rule to output related traffic:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```